# Express/React - stylesheets are 404 in Heroku production (but ok locally)

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku, node-modules

I'm running an Express/React app on Heroku, and the app seems to be unable to find some stylesheets that I'm pulling in from the `/node_modules` directory - however, the app runs fine locally... just flops in production.

In the Express `index.js` file, I'm calling for the stylesheets like so:

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const app = express()
const renderReact = require('./renderReact.js');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css'))
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/quill/dist'))

// THIS APP EMPLOYS SERVER-SIDE RENDERING - THIS IS BASICALLY THE GET REQUEST TO THE HOME ROUTE...
renderReact(app);
```

and when running this on my local machine, the Bootstrap and Quill stylesheets are served up perfectly - they can be found at `http://localhost:3000/css/bootstrap.min.css` etc. as expected.

However, once deployed to Heroku, no such luck - the two stylesheets return 404 errors. Why is it that this works in local development but fails in production? I'd appreciate any advice on how to resolve this issue - thanks!

(Note - this app does utilize Webpack and I'm aware of the `style-loader`... I'd kind of prefer to avoid using that if possible, but I'll do it if it's the only way...)